# Criar um objeto set() vazio

Tags: python

Eu quero criar um objeto do tipo `set` vazio. Para isso eu estou usando a seguinte expressão:

```
objeto = {}
```

Acontece que quando eu faço isso, é criado um objeto do tipo `dict`. O que eu tenho que fazer para criar um objeto do tipo `set` vazio?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bem como você colocou no título, `set` é uma classe predefinida no Python, então basta instanciá-la bem como você faz com qualquer outra classe:

```
objeto = set()
```

Bem como notou, as chaves definem um dicionário vazio, isso por decisão da equipe de desenvolvimento, mas caso queira inicializar um conjunto não vazio, você pode ainda utilizar a sintaxe curta através das chaves:

```
objeto = {1, 2, 3}
```

Neste caso, o que diferenciará o conjunto do dicionário é a presença ou não das chaves separadas do valor pelos dois pontos, `:`.

Como ambos utilizam as chaves, a sintaxe `{}` acaba por ser ambígua. Poderia ser um dicionário vazio; como poderia ser um conjunto vazio. Se considerarmos que a utilização de um conjunto vazio é bem menos recorrente que um dicionário vazio, optaram por esta sintaxe gerar um dicionário.

Comment: Eu vinha instanciando tudo com {}, [] ou (). Com essa descobri que posso usar dict(), list(), tuple(). Obrigado! :)